# Error al enviar una imagen a una API FastAPI(Ubuntu) desde un cliente C#(Windows)

Tags: python, c#, fastapi

Tengo un proyecto en `Fastapi` (`python`) en un servidor `Ubuntu 22` la cual recibe una imagen y tengo un cliente en `C#`(`.net core`).
El cliente `c#` lo que hace es enviarle la imagen a la `api`, cuando el `api` esta en `windows` funciona excelente pero cuando el `api` esta en `Ubuntu` me da el siguiente mensaje:

```
{"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}
```

Código Fastapi:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, BackgroundTasks, UploadFile
import base64
import requests
import os
import logging
from typing import Any



logger = logging.getLogger()
router = APIRouter()



@router.post("/vision", dependencies=[Depends(PermissionRequired('administrators'))])
async def create(file: UploadFile) -> Any:
        # Leer los datos del archivo como bytes
    contents = await file.read()
    
    # Convertir los bytes a formato base64
    base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(contents)
    
    # Decodificar a una cadena (si es necesario)
    base64_image = base64_encoded.decode('utf-8')
    
    return "Correcto"
```

Código Cliente C#:

```
        // Ruta de la imagen a subir
        string imagePath = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\EnvioImagen\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0-windows\\pregunta.jpg";

        // Token de acceso 
        string accessToken = "";

        // Leer contenido de la imagen
        byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);

        // Crear cliente HTTP
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // Añadir cabecera Authorization
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
          new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        // Crear contenido multipart/form-data
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(imageData);
        imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
        content.Add(imageContent, "file", "imagen.jpg");

        // Hacer petición POST a la API
        var response = await client.PostAsync("mi url de mi api  que recibe la imagen", content);
        string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        MessageBox.Show(responseContent);
```

Cabe recalcar que el servidor `Ubuntu` cuenta con todas las librerías necesarias para funcionar y me he asegurado que la ruta de la imagen sea valida, pero como dije desde un comienzo el `api` funciona bien cuando esta bien en `windows10` y al pasarla a `ubuntu22` me da el mensaje antes mencionado. Lo extraño es que con `POSTMAN` función de cualquier forma.

Comment: Agrega un try catch para conseguir más detalles del error.

Comment: por otro lado, ¿son las mismas versiones de python en ambos servidores?

Comment: Si me asegure que sea todas las versiones igual.

Comment: ¿Has probado con diversas imágenes? Según veo en tu código, `.jpeg` != `.jpg`

Comment: No es eso, ya probe, el api me sigue devolviendo esto:   {"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}   y lo que mas me tiene pensando es que con POSTMAN funciona bien.